# Cell opacity Xamarin.Forms iOs

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, opacity, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a **custom renderer** for iOS ListView (with native implementation of iOS ListView) and now, I need to set the opacity for different cells (like in the image below) The cells contains some controls like : image/textlabel/image
[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need custom renderer for setting the opacity of a cell. All to do is set the itemTemplate of list (Use your view instead of `Grid`. All View has `Opacity` property):

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding yourList}> 
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <Grid Opacity="0.5">

          </Grid>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Even all those things if you still want to do it with custom renderers, your costum renderer will be like:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(UIViewCell), typeof(UIViewCellRenderer))]
namespace YourProjectNamespace.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class UIViewCellRenderer: ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item,UITableViewCell reusable, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusable, tv);

            cell.BackgroundColor.ColorWithAlpha(0.5F);// set the opacity
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```